# How do I use the node-rdpjs library?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

I want to connect to my own pc for my school project in nodejs but I'm not sure how to configure the settings.

My code is:

`

```
var rdp = require('node-rdpjs');

var client = rdp.createClient({ 
domain : 'my_domain', 
userName : 'my_username',
password : 'my_password',
enablePerf : true,
autoLogin : true,
decompress : false,
screen : { width : 800, height : 600 },
locale : 'en',
logLevel : 'INFO'
> > }).on('connect', function () {
> > }).on('close', function() {
> > }).on('bitmap', function(bitmap) {
> > }).on('error', function(err) {
> > }).connect('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 3389);
```

`
What do I type in for domain, username, and password. Also what do I do for the .connect function?

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore the domain and set IP, username & password